# How to iterate a list of IWebElements and store in array and then print in console c#

Tags: c#, arrays, linq, selenium

I am learning c# and trying to understand about the arrays.I doing practical usage of arrays in selenium c# and faced a situation, that I cannot able to iterate store their values into an array.My intention is, I want to store all the prices in the array and then go with for loop to iterate one by one in the console.

```
namespace OneDimensionalarray

{

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        IWebDriver driver = null;

        driver = new ChromeDriver();

        driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();

        driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);

        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.shopclues.com/");  

        driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[@id='autocomplete']")). SendKeys("Lenovo");

        driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//span[@id='search']/a")).Click();

        IList<IWebElement> mobileprice = driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//span[@class='p_price']"));


 //I want to store mobiles prices into an array and then print in the console.

        int price = mobileprice.Count;

        int[] prices = new int[price];

        for (int i = 0; i < prices.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(price);
            Console.Read();
        }

    }

    }
}
```

Comment: Where are you stuck? Are you seeing any error? At which line?

Comment: One suggestion I would have if you're new to C# is to learn about Generics and `List<T>`.  You can think of this type as similar to an array, but it resizes as you add elements to it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
I am not seeing any error and also cannot read the prices in console.

Comment: My intention is to get the mobileprices in array and print prices in the console using for loop but nothing displaying

Comment: Based on your code, you are storing mobileprice.Count in a variable.  Then you are creating a `prices` array that you never end up using except to call `prices.Length` which will always be the value of `price`.  Inside your loop, you're not accessing your array.  To do that, you'd need to do something like `prices[i]`, but this isn't going to be too helpful because you never really placed any values in your array.

Comment: If you really just want to print to the Console, you don't need an array for looping over elements.  A foreach loop should be all you need.
```foreach (var we in mobileprices)
{
   ...
}
```
That should loop over the IWebElements, but you'll need to do the work of getting a price from the IWebElement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To store all the prices in the array and then go with for loop to iterate one by one in the console, you can use the following block of code :

```
IList<IWebElement> mobileprice = driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//span[@class='p_price']"));
foreach (IWebElement price in mobileprice )
    Console.WriteLine(price.GetAttribute("innerHTML"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You are creating the array but not populating it with anything before itterating through it.

try (This doesnt use the array - no need for it....)

```
//I want to store mobiles prices into an array and then print in the console.
foreach (IWebElement priceElement in mobileprice )
{
  Console.WriteLine(priceElement.getText());
  Console.Read();
}
```